# How to Enable Flash Plugin in Webview on API 18?

Tags: android, plugins, webview

As I see `PluginState` method is depreciated and `SetPluginsEnabled` is not available in `API 18`.what should i use as an alternate ?

```
 mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_my_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
       // webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

Comment: Adobe discontinued the Flash plugin years ago.

Answer (score 0):

As reported in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginState(android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState)) "Plugins will not be supported in future, and should not be used". No alternatives are available, you can continue use it until will be removed in future Android version, but prepare to stop support for flash web pages and consider to migrate to HTML5.